# How to save array of objects using parse.com server iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Iam using parse.com server to send and retrieve my iOS app data. I want to save list of songs and each song have the following properties(title, artist, album). My code snippet is here;

```
        -(IBAction)saveSongsData:(id)sender {

        PFObject *newPlayer = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Players"];

        /*[newPlayer addObjectsFromArray:self.songsArrray forKey:@"songs"];
        here i got the exception, if i uncomment it*/

        [newPlayer setObject:self.txtPlayerName.text forKey:@"playerName"];
        [newPlayer setObject:self.txtPlayerDesc.text forKey:@"playerDescription"];
        [newPlayer setObject:self.txtPlayerPass.text forKey:@"playerPassword"];

        NSString *objectId = [newPlayer objectId];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:objectId forKey:@"id"];

        [newPlayer saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
            }
            else {
            }
        }];
        }
```

Where `self.songsArray` is an array of songs objects having following properties;

- title, 
        artist,
        album.

  But when i try to save my songs data by using this line of code.

  ```
      [newPlayer addObjectsFromArray:self.songsArrray forKey:@"songs"];
  ```

  I got an exception and this is the message:-

  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:     'PFObject values must be serializable to JSON'

  Please help me, how to send my songs data to server in JSON format.
      Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to save the array? [newPlayer save]; I think is how you do it with parse.

Comment: If i have for example, 7 songs in self.songsArray. Then how to serialize that data in JSON format and save that data using PFObject?OR is there another possibility?

Comment: Have you checked out their REST API? https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-classes

Comment: You should probably make the songs objects actual PFObjects, which are part of the parse DB. Then associated the songs with the player (either by ID or relation).

Comment: Thanks @STANGMMX, It helped to sort out my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with Parse, your arrays and dictionaries can only contain objects that can be serialized to JSON. It looks as if `self.songsArray` contains objects that cannot be automatically converted to JSON. You have two options - use objects that are compatible with Parse or, as someone has suggested in the comments, make your songs `PFObjects` and then associate them with the player via a relationship.

Comment: I am doing like this and its working fine now:)                                            PFObject *songObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Songs"];
[songObject setObject:songs.title forKey:@"title"];       [songObject setObject:songs.album forKey:@"album"];
[songObject setObject:songs.artist forKey:@"artist"];       [songObject save];                                             Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could try one these options:

1) If you want to save an array of Parse Objects you can use the following:

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground: self.songsArray block: YOUR_BLOCK];
```

2) You can create Parse.com relations:

```
PFObject *newPlayer ...
PFRelation *relation = [newPlayer relationforKey:@"songs"];
[relation addObject:song];  // add as many songs as you want.
[newPlayer saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the objectId `NSString`.

Then to retreive, do some fancy stuff like this.

```
[query2 whereKey:PF_CHAT_SETID equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:PF_SET_CLASS_NAME objectId:setId_]];
```